# using interface keyword as variable name in Visual Studio/Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

I have a project which uses a lot of variable name `interface`. This keyword is not allowed in Visual C++. I have to do

```
#ifdef interface
#undef interface
#endif
```

for every file that uses this keyword. Is there a way to cleanly do that at the project level? Or is there a compiler flag for Visual C++ to not define this keyword for `struct`?

Comment: What version of the Visual Studio are you using? A simple program with `int interface = 1;` compiles fine for me on Visual Studio 2019, even when I disable the conformance mode by specifying the `/permissive` flag.

Comment: Oh, if you are using Windows headers, just make sure you `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before you  `#include <windows.h>`.

Comment: @heapunderrun VS2019, the `interface` is defined in combaseapi.h. Some header may include this before.

Comment: @heapunderrun I added #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN  before <winsock.h> which also include <windows.h> but it doesn't work

Comment: just to confirm the solution, define the WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN at the project level will work: add_definitions(-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN)